# What's the fate of the tailed beasts and Sasuke after chapter 698?

Tags: naruto

The fight between Naruto and Sasuke was brutal. It pushed them both to their limits.

In the last page, it is shown that both lose one of their hands.
Sasuke admits defeat. I was actually shocked to see that picture.
Never imagined the fight could lead up to that.

- **Now that Sasuke has finally acknowledged Naruto, does it mean Sasuke
  will now help Naruto?**
- **Where does it leave the future of the tailed beasts though, since Sasuke's intention was to kill them?**

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for the last two chapters to find out... For all we know they may both die from blood loss...

Comment: Actually they won't die from the blood loss, alteast not Naruto. Since in the movie, they have shown naruto with a bandage to his hands, I guess from that ,we can infer that naruto isn't dead.

Comment: Could you please explain the down-vote? I wonder why i got it.

Comment: i'm not the down voter but i could explain a reason why i would've downvote. in my opinion any answer currently posted will be entirely speculation and opinion based since Naruto x Sasuke Yaoi fans would want them to hook up now, others would now want Sasuke to return and be with Sakura (i personally want to see a Sakura x Ino pairing, stuff Sasuke and Shikamaru) and here we'd rather want answers with some cited evidence or logical/observational basis.

Comment: (cont.) Since we know Naruto is ending in a couple of chapters and this question will most likely be answered then anyway, to me this question reads *"I want to know what happens next and i can't wait, give me inside info on the story"* and unless Masashi Kishimoto has been answering question on this site that ain't happening (doubt they'd spoil unreleased content anyway)

Comment: Did you say Shikamaru with Ino ? What happened to Temari den?

Comment: @Memor-X I am really confused. you say, Sakura belongs to Ino?!!! Ino and Sakura are girls. Am sure you are not talking about lesbian interest. Also, I don't understand what 'Senko' is ?. Pls let me know if I don't understand something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sasuke gave up on killing the tailed beasts.

- Sasuke - returned to hidden leaf village, and then went to explore the world.
- Kurama - returned to Naruto, presumably now Naruto has a whole Kurama (as opposed to just Yin or just Yang)
- Gyuki - returned to Killer Bee.
- Rest of the bijuu, undetermined, presumably they were sent free. All of them can still converge and speak to each other due to all of them giving Naruto a portion of their chakra.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly doubt Naruto can die due to the fact he has a bijuu in him. Though...the question that arises to that, if kyuubi has no chakra then that means Naruto has a possible chance of seeing death.

Comment: Note, Kurama Himself even says it would be inconvenient if Naruto dies because he dies to, and it takes time to reincarnate. Jinchuriki can die without the tailed beast being extracted. That is what happened with Rin and the 3 tails (Isobu), and presumably also how he got free from the fourth Mizukage before he was captured by Deidara.

Answer (score 1):

The rest of the beast is set free. their wish was to roam free. after so long being traped and used by humans. but they sure will give naruto a hand if he needs them.